# Is Hydrogen ion an acid?

Tags: acid-base

I had an argument with a friend about this question. He says it is not an acid But I think it is as it itself can increase the pH value.

Comment: This is an un-question. If you argue about it or have an opinion on it, then you are wrong.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin. Why do you think it is an un-question ? This proposed question may have been a consequence of Arrhenius' theory of acids. Why not ?

Comment: Can you have a mole of hydrogen ions in a beaker? Yes and no.

Comment: Not to complicate things but the "hydrogen ion" is one of the fundamental particles - our friend the proton.

Comment: @Hal technically, since protons are composed of the fundamental particle, quarks, a proton would be considered a hadron.

Comment: @DVAL98 Your point is well taken.  The use of "fundamental particle" was not the best of terms.  Given the discipline [chemistry not physics] and the apparent level of the question, it seemed helpful to make the point that a proton is one of the three particles most often discussed by chemists.  It also helps make the point that H+ is never along, and hence emphasize  the importance of the H3O+ discussion.

Comment: @Hal I apologize if that sounded pompous. In it was just semantics which can be annoying and your point was well delivered (and important). I just wanted to clarify for OP/future readers. The hard part of communication on online forums is trying to convey a point without seeming condescending.